# Flutter Custom DatePicker

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dialog

Does anyone know a framework or any way to make a datepicker like this?

[image]

Comment: You can try using CupertinoDatePicker.https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoDatePicker-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks very common with holo date picker so you can try [holo date picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_holo_date_picker)

[image]